# Restore swappiness on SSD

Tags: ssd, swap

I've just installed Xubuntu 18.04.3, and I was running some wrong commands we can't run on a SSD. How to do to go back? I have a SSD and no partition Swap.
Here are the commands:

```
echo vm.swappiness=5 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf 
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

To fix it, I was running these commands:

```
echo vm.swappiness=1 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf 
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf 
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf
```

What do you think? Was the problem fixed?

Comment: First off... never blindly follow instructions you find on the web... unless YOU KNOW WHAT THE COMMANDS DO. Second... vm.swappiness should probably never be set to 1 or 5. Third... 99-sysctl.conf and 99-swappiness.conf would be the wrong files to create/write to. Manually edit those two files and remove the commands you added.

Comment: Yes  I removed the commands in the **99-sysctl.conf** but if I remove the commands in **99-swappiness.conf** file, the file becomes empty (no more lines in there). Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, as I mention below, if the file just contained the two lines that you added... just delete the file. What lesson did we learn today :-)

Answer (score 4):

What problem are you experiencing?  What is your goal?

The first two commands you show add lines to the `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` file.

```
echo vm.swappiness=5 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

The second set of commands add lines to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf`, **which is a different file than the previous file**.

```
echo vm.swappiness=1 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf 
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf
```

---

It is unclear what you are asking, but if you want to 'undo' the first set of commands, the easiest thing to do would be to open `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` in a text editor and remove the two lines you added.  You will need to do this with both files to undo everything you've done.

Comment: These commands are taken from a website. They are used to manage memory usage but it seems that we can't  run these commands on a SSD. So I just want to remove all these commands and reset  the settings as before.

Comment: I removed the two lines from the **/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf**.  But what about **/etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf** file? What were the settings **in /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf** before?

Comment: If 99-swappiness.conf contains just two lines... just delete the file... and reboot. Then do `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness` and it should return 60. And... what you did has nothing to do with SSD.

Comment: OK. Last question: can I install zram to avoid swap related entries?